# Coding a simple loop for a sliding window

Tags: r, loops, sliding-window

I have the following problem. I have a time series made by 2659 observations. I need to perform a statistical test over a sliding window of length 256 and each time I want to extract the p-values from these tests and gather them into a time series vector. To perform this test (runs test) I want as threshold a moving average that moves along with the data and the rolling window. Here is my attemp (in R)

```
x<- ts(rnorm(2659, mean = 0.0001, sd = 0.0001))
library(randtests)
for(i in 1:2404){

     runs  <- runs.test(x[i:i+255], threshold = mean(x[i:i+255]))
     ret[i] <- runs$p.value 

}
```

The index starts from 1 but stops to 2404 because the time window must move of 256 each time, therefore the first window goes from 1 to 256, the second from 2 to 257... and finally stops to 255+2404 = 2659. I hope that I made clear my problem, I do not understand why it does not work. Of course I need to plot the result over time to have in a plot all the p-values over the time. I hope you can help me.

PS: Please, set a seed if you propose an example so that I can reproduce your results.

Comment: use `[i:(i+255)]`; testing: `1:1+5` vs. `1:(1+5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rollapplyr` with the indicated function.

```
library(zoo)
pv <- function(xx) runs.test(xx, threshold = mean(xx))$p.value
out <- rollapplyr(x, 256, pv, fill = NA)
```

### Note

```
library(randtests)
set.seed(123)
x <- ts(rnorm(2659, mean = 0.0001, sd = 0.0001))
```

Comment: It seems to me a perfect answer, but I've got only a perplexity: are we sure that mean(x) computes a sliding window average and not an average over the whole dataset?

Comment: Arguments are local to their function and override any object of the same name outside the function.  I have changed `x` to `xx` to provide additional clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Two changes to your existing code should make it work:

```
set.seed(0)
x <- ts(rnorm(2659, mean = 0.0001, sd = 0.0001))
library(randtests)
ret <- rep(NA, length(x))
for(i in 1:2404){
    runs  <- runs.test(x[i:(i+255)], threshold = mean(x[i:(i+255)]))
    ret[i] <- runs$p.value
}
```

First change is to initialize the `ret` variable before the loop. `ret <- rep(NA, length(x))`

The second change is to add the parenthesis, i.e. `x[i:(i+255)]`. If you do `x[i:i+255]`, you will get a single return value, `x[i]`.